# attach two images to fbo for mrt rendering

Tags: c++, c, opengl, framebuffer, fbo

I want to attach two render targets to a fbo, so I can render to two targets at once. I have one function that accepts two render targets.

```
void render(struct glhexbutton *_this, GLuint target0, GLuint target1)
{
  GLenum buffers[2];
  GLfloat vertices[] = { -1.0, -1.0,
                         -1.0,  1.0,
                          1.0, -1.0,
                          1.0,  1.0  };

  GLubyte indices[] = { 0, 1, 2,
                        1, 2, 3  };

  GLuint fbo;

  struct {
      int x;
      int y;
  } position;


  /*Load variables into shader program*/
  glUniform4f(glhexbutton_static.uni_address, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _this->data.texture);
  glUniform1i(glhexbutton_static.uni_texture, /*GL_TEXTURE*/0); 
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  glUseProgram(_this->data.static_data->program);

  /*create fbo and attach render targets*/

  glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                       target0, 0);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                       target1, 0);

  /*Set the viewport of the fbo*/

  position.x = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)*_this->data.position.relative.x+_this->data.position.offset.x;
  position.y = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT)*_this->data.position.relative.y+_this->data.position.offset.y;
  glViewport(position.x, position.y,
             _this->data.size.width, _this->data.size.height);

  buffers[0] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
  buffers[1] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1;

  glDrawBuffers(2, buffers);



  glEnableVertexAttribArray(_this->data.static_data->att_coord);
  glVertexAttribPointer(_this->data.static_data->att_coord,
                        2,
                        GL_FLOAT,
                        GL_FALSE,
                        0,
                        vertices);
  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(_this->data.static_data->att_coord);


  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
  glDeleteFramebuffers(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, &fbo);
}
```

my vertex shader:

```
#version 330
attribute vec2 coord;
varying vec2 f_coord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(coord, 0.0, 1.0);
  f_coord = (1.0+coord)/2.0;
}
```

my pixel/fragment shader:

```
#version 330
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec4 address;
varying vec2 f_coord;
void main() {
  gl_FragData[0]=texture2D(texture,f_coord);
  gl_FragData[1]=address;
  if(texture2D(texture,f_coord).a == 0.0)
    discard;
}
```

When I call

```
render(glhexbutton, 0, texture);
```

or

```
render(glhexbutton, texture, 0);
```

I just get a black blank screen

Answer (score 1):

> I want to attach two render targets to the default fbo, so I can render to two targets at once.

There is **no** default FBO. There is a *default framebuffer*, and that is the one provided by the drawable you bind your context to (typically a window). You cannot attach textures/render buffers to the default FB, and the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT`s are not valid for `glDrawBuffer` in the default FB. So your code will just produce some GL errors and continue to render in single render target mode, to what ever draw buffer was set before.

Comment: I've updated the code, I've added two lines for creating and binding the fbo, and two lines for unbinding and deleting the fbo. But now I get a blank screen.

Comment: @user2798943: Sure you do. Because you now render into textures, but not onto the screen. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but what you currently do dos not make sense. As a side note: Enabling a draw buffer for some color attachment where nothing is bound (your '0' case) will lead to invalid state. You can use `GL_NONE` in such cases. If you somehow think that attaching texture 0 to some FBO and end up rendering into the default FB again, you are wrong. You either render to some FBO, or to the default FB, and cen never mix both.

Comment: Okay, I've changed the code so both arguments are now texture ids. Okay target0 renders fine now, but not target1. target1 one keeps blank.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no default offscreen fbo, you need to implement a ping-pong scheme in your code, and then use the FBO as input texture for the drawing to display. You can take a look at the simple code in sgxperf for a working example of setting up FBO and using it to render to a display, gist here `https://gist.github.com/prabindh/8173489`